# Change Root Directory on server properties page in SQL Server 2014 SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-server-2014

We did in inplace upgrade from `SQL 2012 to SQL 2014` (I know it wasn't the best choice, and it won't happen again, so no need to beat that horse). I have both the `MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER` and `MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER` Folders. The database operates correctly, but the data is located in the MSSQL11 folder which isn't a problem for us, but... in the Server Management Studio under server properties the 'root directory' field on the general page points to the MSSQL12 folder, and our automated backup system (which is part of a larger software suite) uses that field to place the backups in the MSSQL12 folder.

**Question:**

- I'd like to change the 'root directory' to point to MSSQL11 and have
  the data and backups in one place.
- Does anyone know what that field is used for (besides the obvious
  backup system)?
- Is it relatively safe to change it?

I would of course take a snapshot of the VM before changing and test it before I went live, but I wanted to avoid problems if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that you can change an instance's root directory after installation. I would probably bite the bullet and play it safe, back up your user databases, remove the instance, clean up the folders, and reinstall. You can probably change the location that SQL Server will use for backups, but that depends on how exactly your automated backup system determines where to put the files in the first place (and I would probably guess that you can override that by telling it, manually, where to put them). Placing the backup files on the same drive as SQL Server is not that safe anyway.

Comment: You cannot change root directory without uninstalling and reinstalling.There is no problem in changing default backup path. You can refer to [How to change default backup path](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1583/changing-the-default-sql-server-backup-folder/). There wont be any side affects as such

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The default backup directory is set correctly in the registry, it's just that my software vendor's backup grabs the 'root directory ' instead of doing something more intelligent. Ultimately they need to change their program, and I would think it's an easy change, but until they do I'm stuck unless it is safe to change that server property...

Comment: Not only is it not safe to change that server property, it's not possible, at least through the UI (it's read only). You may be able to find the corresponding location in the registry, and change it there, but I suspect that if you change the registry underneath SQL Server, it will simply refuse to start. How many databases are you backing up on this server? Maybe the easiest solution right now is to manage the backups for this server manually (until you can fix it *right*) and tell your inflexible backup software to stop looking at it. How it thinks backing up to root directory makes sense...

Comment: You should also disclose which automated backup solution you are using. Maybe someone knows how to override that property, or they can be shamed into fixing this faster. What they're doing now is just plain wrong.

Comment: We use a full software package called PCS. It does backups to the proper directory in the MSSQL12 Folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup), not the root. To answer directly, we have 3 databases, all are related to this proprietary software. We can't backup manually, because it is integral to the update system of said software. If it isn't safe to change that incorrect 'root directory' field in the server properties I'll deal with the backups being in the wrong directory. I really appreciate you all taking the time to help us. Thanks!

Comment: @Demian McLellan, Are you able to solve the issue?